# Join from left side without references for @ManyToMany

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I have three tables.

```
LEFT ---------|<- LEFT_RIGHT ->|--------- RIGHT
```

```java
@Entity
class Left {
    // no collection mapping for LeftRight
}

@Entity
class Right {
    // no collection mapping for LeftRight
}

@Entity
class LeftRight {

    @JoinColumn(name="LEFT_ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private Left left;

    @JoinColumn(name="RIGHT_ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private Right right;
}
```

Note that neither `Left` nor `Right` doesn't have any reference for `LeftRight`s.

Is there any way with Criteria-API to selecting from `Left` while joining to `LeftRight`?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a criteria query for `LeftRight` and use projection to retrieve the `left` property:

```
session.createCriteria(LeftRight.class)
    // Add whatever restrictions on Left properties
    .createCriteria("left")
    .add(Restrictions.like("name", "%something%"))
    // Use projection to retrieve the left property
    .setProjection(Projections.property("left"));
```

Comment: The above code uses the Hibernate API, which is not the JPA Criteria API. Could you show how do the above with the JPA Criteria API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use a selection.

```
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
Root r = cq.from(LeftRight.class);
cq.select(r.get("left"));
cq.where(...);
Query query = em.createQuery(cq);
```

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#CriteriaQuery